# "downloading and installing softwareware on Windows 10 Phone"

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to make an auto-install that downloads and auto-install automaticly when the user
clicks on a link for Windows 10 Modile

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done, would be a security vulnerability if it could. If by "auto-install automatically" you are OK with the OS asking the user to confirm that yes, they want to install this app, then you can do that in at least two ways.

#### If the app is in the store

Just give the user a link to the relevant Store app, on the web. The Store application on the phone should automatically open to the same app, and will have an "Install" button. You can test this with, for example, this link to the OneBusAway app: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/onebusaway/9nblggh0cbd9

#### If the app needs to be sideloaded

If your app is only available as an unpublished package (.xap, appx, or .appxbundle), you won't be able to install it at all if the user hasn't configured their phone to allow installing untrusted applications ("sideloading"), which is a setting under Settings -> Update & security -> For developers -> Sideload apps. However, for phones with sideloading enabled, any method of "opening" the app package (such as from a web page, an email attachment, a ZIP file, on OneDrive or other cloud service, sent through Skype or similar, etc.) should open a "Do you want to install this app?" page for the user, with some basic info about the app and "Install" or "Cancel" buttons.